# Seeking guidance on integrating FCM and Firebase with Django 2.2 for Flutter app notifications

Tags: django, flutter, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

**
I'm working on a project where I need to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with Django 2.2 for sending push notifications to a Flutter app. However I am not familiar with Django 2.2 and the client has explicitly requested that we do not update their project at this time. I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this integration while keeping the project on Django 2.2. I have the following questions:**

1. Is it possible to integrate FCM and Firebase with Django 2.2 to send push notifications to a Flutter app? Are there any recommended libraries or packages that are compatible with Django 2.2 for FCM integration?
2. Since I'm not familiar with Django REST Framework, can someone explain how to handle FCM requests and extract the FCM token in Django 2.2? It would be really helpful if you could provide some code examples or guidance.
3. How can I generate the necessary notification code to activate notifications in the Flutter app without relying on Django REST Framework? Are there any recommended practices or methods for dynamically generating the code or payload using the FCM token within the context of Django 2.2?

I haven't started the implementation yet, but I'm aware that **websockets** could be a potential solution for integrating FCM and Firebase with Django 2.2 for push notifications in a Flutter app without updating the project. I would appreciate insights on the feasibility and best practices of using websockets with Django 2.2 for push notifications, along with any recommended libraries or resources for implementation.

Thank you for your help!